# How to create an overlay window over a certain element via AccessibilityService and scroll it too?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, accessibility, accessibilityservice

I need to put an overlay Window **precisely** over a certain element of a third-party app, pixel by pixel or nearly so.

I'm aware of:

```
//.............
appOverlayLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
appOverlayLayoutParams.x = 100;
appOverlayLayoutParams.y = 100;
//.............
```

However, this won't place an overlay window precisely where I'll need because the coordinates are static.

How will I do it? How to make them dynamic? How to get the ones of an element? Assuming that I've it in `onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent e) { .... }`

I'd also prefer an overlay window to follow an element if and when it gets scrolled.

Comment: What's the scenario that you need this for?

Comment: @aled a task I've been given

Comment: It seems like an abuse of the accessibility service and potentially a security issue.

Comment: @aled I couldn't care less what it seems to you